# Function that accepts any number of objects and returns a single object that contains all the fields of the original objects

Tags: javascript, object

I need to write a zip function. It accepts any number of objects and returns a single object that contains all the fields of the original objects. If the same key is found in several objects, you should leave the value that was found first.

I've tried it this way, but it returns undefined. Please tell me how to do it right?

```js
function zip(...objects) {
  const resultObj = objects.reduce((prevVal, item) => {
    for (let key in item) {
      if (!prevVal[key]) {
        prevVal[key] = item[key];
      } else {
        return
      }
    }
    return prevVal
  }, {})
  return resultObj
}

// example
const objects = [
  { foo: 2, bar: 1 },
  { foo: 8, baz: 4 } // foo - repeating key
];


console.log(zip(...objects)); // should be { foo: 2, bar: 1, baz: 4 } but receive undefined
```

Comment: see that `return` ... that means `prevVal` will be `undefined` in the next iteration - simply remove that line

Comment: also, `Object.assign({},...objects.slice().reverse());` will do the same as your code ... reverse for obvious reasons

Comment: Max, do you understand why you need to remove the `return` in the `else` - a) it stops the loop early, and b) it breaks the reduce (not in this case, since it happened on the last object, if you had a third object, an error would be thrown)